# Does setting a timeout and retries with 'RetrySettings' on the bigquery-api take care of server timeout issues, or is this only client side?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add some data to a bigquery table and want to retry for write failures. I found a library function to retry writing data if we set a maximum number of retry attempts and a total timeout. 
Will this function take care of the timeout errors below? Also, will it be triggered only if an exception is thrown, or also when only a few rows are missed(in which case the bigquery-api returns success)?

Code snippet:

```
    RetrySettings retrySettings = RetrySettings.newBuilder()
    .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(16)).setMaxAttempts(3).build();
```

Logs:

```
    2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 
    [ERROR] Failed on errors : 13 / 500
    2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 
    [ERROR] {
    "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
    10.73.74.131:25988 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
    "location" : "",
    "message" : "",
    "reason" : "timeout"
    }
    2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 
    [ERROR] {
    "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
    10.73.104.139:14782 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
    "location" : "",
    "message" : "",
    "reason" : "timeout"
    }
    2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 
    [ERROR] {
    "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
    10.73.104.5:26078 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
    "location" : "",
    "message" : "",
    "reason" : "timeout"
    }
    2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 [ERROR] {
   "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
   10.73.156.197:26110 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
   "location" : "",
   "message" : "",
   "reason" : "timeout"
   }
   2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 
   [ERROR] {
   "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
   10.73.29.69:25588 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
   "location" : "",
   "message" : "",
   "reason" : "timeout"
   }
   2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 [ERROR] {
   "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
   10.73.253.134:25986 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
   "location" : "",
   "message" : "",
   "reason" : "timeout"
   }
   2017-09-12 15:29:02.961 c.y.d.m.b.MawBigQueryClient pool-12-thread-16 [ERROR] {
   "debugInfo" : "bigtable::Deadline missed: /BTI_TabletServer.Apply to 
   10.73.49.2:14832 : DEADLINE_EXCEEDED",
   "location" : "",
   "message" : "",
   "reason" : "timeout"
   }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit further on how you use 'retrySettings' in your code?